# Nativescript bottom navigation on android doesn't render as expected

Tags: angular, nativescript, bottomnavigationview

I created a NativeScript app and cut/paste the code directly from the NativeScript site for BottomNavigation and when I run it in the android simulator the bottom navigation renders into a small box in the upper left of the android screen (it doesn't take up the screen and put the navigation at the bottom as it does on the iOS simulator.

I have tried (what feels) like everything I can think of including adding height/width, adding a gridlayout with columns and rows set to * etc.

Is there a secret to getting this to render on Android that I'm missing?

The code I have is straight from the Nativescript page on BottomNavigation:

```
<!-- The bottom tab UI is created via TabStrip (the containier) and TabStripItem (for each tab)-->
<TabStrip>
    <TabStripItem>
        <Label text="Home"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf015;" class="fas"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>

    <TabStripItem class="special">
        <Label text="Account"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf007;" class="fas"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>

    <!-- 
        The below two conventions (shorthand vs exteded syntax) are identical in UI outcome but the second one will provide you with greater control over your TabStripItem UI.
        When using the first shorthand syntax then your Icon Font CSS class should be set on the BottomNavigation element.
     -->
    <!-- <TabStripItem title="Search" iconSource="font://&#xf00e;"></TabStripItem> -->
    <TabStripItem class="special">
        <Label text="Search"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf00e;" class="fas"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
</TabStrip>

<!-- The number of TabContentItem components should corespond to the number of TabStripItem components -->
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Label text="Home Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Label text="Account Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Label text="Search Page" class="h2 text-center"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping this content inside BottomNavigation tag?
I am using same and it is working for me.

Comment: It is in mine, apparently I didn't copy that for some reason.  But it still isn't working for me.  But re-verified that it is an exact copy of what is on the Nativescript page (including the bottom navigation tags) and it still renders as about a one inch square in the upper left of my android simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nativescript 8+, Tabs and BottomNavigation have been removed from core and are now separate plugins, see blog post for details: https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-8-announcement/#important-note-about-bottomnavigation-and-tabs